# Comparing two UITextFields

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have no idea why this isn't working and I feel it's something really very stupid.. I'm trying to compare two textfields (like a confirming the password type of thing) but it just isn't working!! Ive tried several different options and none of them work. I've tried:

```
if (passwordCheckField1.text == passwordCheckField2.text) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue4" sender:nil];
    }
```

I've tried:

```
NSString *retrivedPasswordCheckField1 = passwordCheckField1.text;
NSString *retrivedPasswordCheckField2 = passwordCheckField2.text;
if ([retrivedPasswordCheckField1 isEqualToString:retrivedPasswordCheckField2]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue4" sender:nil];
    }
```

I've tried:

```
if ([passwordCheckField1.text isEqualToString:retrivedPasswordCheckField2.text]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue4" sender:nil];
    }
```

I've implement the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in the .h and i've also set the delegates for both fields, (`passwordCheckField1.delegate = self;
    passwordCheckField2.delegate = self;`)

What am I missing???? Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I probably should mention that I'm using a Navigation Controller, with several child view controllers. Each contains a text field, so when the view controller about the first password comes up, the user enters it and then clicks next taking them to the confirm password view controller. All are linked to the same class files.

Comment: Are you sure that strings are equal?

Comment: Have you tried to `NSLog` both compared passwords? `isEqualToString` should work just fine for this case

Comment: Put `NSlog` in your delegate methods

Comment: you are comparing these string in after which? like after pressing a button or something show us some more code or explain the work flow

Comment: Try: `if ([passwordCheckField1.text isEqualToString:passwordCheckField2.text])`. Also NSLog both as well as their lengths.

Comment: Yes, I have NSLged them, and they defiantly are equal.

Comment: just try once  [self resignFirstResponder]; before comparing text

Comment: isEqualToString method should work. I am also using same method. Check your both textfields IBOutlet property names. Have you assign right IBOutlet property on textfield. May there will property assigning issue.

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
NSString *password = passwordCheckField1.text;
NSString *confirmPassword = passwordCheckField2.text;

NSLog(@"password: '%@'", password);
NSLog(@"confirmPassword: '%@'", confirmPassword);

if([password isEqualToString: confirmPassword]) {
       NSLog(@"Match");

} else {
        NSLog(@"Not Match");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This logs Not Match. I'm so confused right now.. hehe, but thanks anyway!

Comment: So, the strings do not match, fix that. NSLog them in this test code.

Comment: This is really odd. Before I got to the if statement above, I NSLogged the first password, and lets say I typed in awesome, it came up awesome. All good. Then i got to the if statement and entered the second password and it logged that the first password is now equal to (null). Does that give any help? Because I still can't figure it out... :P

Comment: I should be able to check text field values from different methods in the same class files shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (passwordCheckField1.text == passwordCheckField2.text) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue4" sender:nil];
}
```

The above code doesn't compare two string values. It actually compares two pointers value.So it is not going to be useful for you.

but code

`if ([retrivedPasswordCheckField1 isEqualToString:retrivedPasswordCheckField2]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue4" sender:nil];
    }`

should have compared the string values. May be string your values are not same or `nil`. Have you printed the  `passwordCheckField1.text` and    `passwordCheckField2.text`.What is the values for two strings ?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I input the values with the keyboard and NSLog them and they are the same. I will try this! :)

Comment: Check the string length for two strings.These lengths must be same

Answer (score 1):

chk your values.

```
 if ([passwordCheckField1.text isEqualToString:passwordCheckField2.text]) {   
    //Match it's working for me 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if([[passwordCheckField1 text] isEqualToString:[passwordCheckField2 text]])
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue4" sender:nil];
}
else
{
   //not matched
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a precautionary measure, try triming both the password strings for leading and trailing spaces before comparing like

```
NSString *pwd1 = [pwdTxtField1.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]];
```